# Mapping between two arrays of observable classes

Tags: angular, dictionary, rxjs, observable

I have two given classes `SgFormsBase`and `QuestionBase` with slightly different member names, and I want to translate `observable[]` of one to the other.

```
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { map} from 'rxjs/operators'

class SgFormsBase{
  constructor(
     public id: number,
     public survey: string
  ){}
}

class QuestionBase{
  constructor(
     public qid: number,
     public qsurvey: string
  ){}
}

const a = new SgFormsBase(11, 'Endo')
const b = new SgFormsBase(12, 'Kolo')
const sg = of([a, b] )

function toQuestionsBase(sgforms: Observable<SgFormsBase[]>): Observable<QuestionBase[]> {
  return sgforms.pipe(map(
     sgform =>  new QuestionBase(sgform.id, sgform.survey)))
}

toQuestionsBase(sg)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the source observable is an observable of `SgFormsBase[]`, each value it emits is a whole array. The observable `map` operator therefore receives the entire array. You need another array map operator inside the observable `map` operator.

```
function toQuestionsBase(sgforms: Observable<SgFormsBase[]>): Observable<QuestionBase[]> {
  return sgforms.pipe(map(
    sgforms => sgforms.map(sgform => new QuestionBase(sgform.id, sgform.survey))))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the parameter *sgForms* resolves with an *array* of *SgFormsBase*. So, what you'll need to do is *emit* each value individually, *map* the individual values to *QuestionBase instances* and then zip it back up into an *array*.

```
function toQuestionsBase(sgforms: Observable<SgFormsBase[]>): Observable<QuestionBase[]> {
  return sgforms.pipe(
    mergeMap((sgs: SgFormsBase[]) => sgs),
    map((sgForm: SgFormsBase) => new QuestionBase(sgForm.id, sgForm.survey)), 
    toArray());
}
```

Comment: The version of @cristian.t works, and your's looks interesting to me. Too bad, it does not compile because of `Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<SgFormsBase, QuestionBase>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<T, QuestionBase>'.
  Type 'SgFormsBase' is not assignable to type 'T'.`

Comment: Interesting. I've had some intermittent issues with my reactive streams compilation in the recent times. They work as expected, nonetheless. I posted this code in one of my project and it did not show any compilation error. Here's my versions:

RxJS: Version 6.4.0
Local Typescript: Version 3.4.1
Global Typescript: Version 3.1.1

Comment: Same version for me. compilerOptions: strict: true, module es2015

Comment: Same. Does your builder let you run the code? I don't understand why SgFormsBase can't be type casted into a generic class T.

Comment: Yes, it is a run-time fault, not a compile fault. I just rebuild my full node_module from scratch, same result.

Comment: The only generic T I see is in toArray. I tried a few variants of toArray<> with no success. As a R-programmer, I have lost contact with this typesafe stuff evidently.

Comment: Accepted tick goes to @cristian.t as a New Contributor.

Comment: Check this out. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayehjd?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I installed it on my computer, and got warning `Your global Angular CLI version (7.3.6) is greater than your local version (7.0.7). The local Angular CLI version is used.` Program run ok. Don't know how the CLI version would come in the way. Thanks, I have to leave now.