# combine 2 observables into 1 with condition in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, observable, subscription

I have an ionic-angular app which loads 2 observables from google firestore.

Observable A returns an array of objects (group).
Observable B returns an array of objects (contacts).

```
group = [ name: string, adminID: string ]
contact = [ name: string, userID: string ]
```

Now i want to combine these two subscriptions with following condition:

```
if ( group.adminID = contact.userID ) {
   group.adminData = contact
}
```

and return this as one array.

I tried it with combineLatest but i am really new with rxjs and didn't found an solution.
I am also not sure that combineLatest is the right function for this case, but i think this isn't a hard task for pros!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip).

```
Observable.zip(groupObservable, contactObservable).subscribe(
  ([group, contact]) => {
    if ( group.adminID = contact.userID ) {
      group.adminData = contact
    }
  }
);
```

Based on your requirement you could also use [`combineLatest`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest). The difference is while `zip` waits for all the observables to emit a value before pushing it, `combineLatest` will push new values even if one of the observable emits a value, given that both observables have already emitted atleast one value.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using **Observables**, you can use **Pipe** and then **Map** to merge two array

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators

Maybe this answer help you:

[Mapping between two arrays of observable classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55538941/mapping-between-two-arrays-of-observable-classes/55539348)

Comment: Michael D had the right answer to my question and this is also the solution. I tried promises before but this doesn't work. Merging arrays isn't the problem, handle a merge with 2 subscriptions is the problem. and this is solved with the solution of Michael D.